# SO for Teams sales pitch SVG renders incorrectly in Firefox and Chrome on Linux

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) page, an [SVG image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/illo-quick.svg) is included in the sales pitch next to the *quick: bite-sized answers to your team’s questions* paragraph. It does not render correctly in Firefox 59.0.2 nor Chrome 66.0.3359.139 on 64-bit Linux, as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of SVG in which inline code has been shifted to the right.]

Other browsers on other operating systems are likely also affected.

The [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Question-and-Answer@4x-602x675.png) shown in the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-available/) announcing the release of Stack Overflow for Teams has non-shifted inline code in the same image, which I believe should be the correct rendering of the SVG.

Comment: thanks for the report @Justastudent - I'm passing it on to the right people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) has [edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/367261/4) my question to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) ...

I am confirming that the issue has been resolved now.